# Json needs to be parsed twice?

Tags: json, python-3.x, dictionary, beautifulsoup, unicode-escapes

I have json string that I have collected from a website with bs4 that has a formatting with escape characters:

Code when trying to parse:

data.html:

```
<script> 
var variable_json = JSON.parse("{\u0022id\u0022:1990,\u0022media_id\u0022:\u00225299\u0022}")
</script>
```

Scraping the html data:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(data.html, "html.parser")
script = (soup.find("script").strip().replace("var variable_json = JSON.parse(", "").replace(');','')
```

`json_dict = json.loads(script)`

Output:

```
{"id":1990,"media_id":"5299"}
*This does not work*
```

When I try to get the value of a key it returns an error: `json_dict["id"]` ,
`TypeError: string indices must be integers`

However I had recently discovered a temporary solution that solves this problem in which I have to parse it twice using the json.loads:

Code for the solution:

`json_dict = json.loads(json.loads(script))`

Output:

```
{'id' : 1990, 'media_id' : '5299'}
*This works the best*
```

And this actually acts like a dictionary instead of a string object

**Now for my question**
Is there actually no other better way than parsing it twice? Or is there a better more pythonic method?

I have several hypothesis that there is a certain function that parses an escape character `\u0022Text\u0022` to `"Text"` without using `json.loads()` so I would love to be informed if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

No, do not load twice.

I think there is at least 1 typo in the definition of `collected`. At a minimum it needs a closing double quote. I ignored it and simply used the value of `json_dict` that you provided:

```
{"id":1990,"media_id":"5299"}
```

As you can see there is no problem accessing the value of `id`:

```
$ python
Python 3.8.6 (default, Jan 27 2021, 15:42:20)
[GCC 10.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> json_dict={"id":1990,"media_id":"5299"}
>>> json_dict['id']
1990
>>> json_dict["media_id"]
'5299'
```

Comment: You seemed to ignore the that the data I collected has escape characters

Comment: The string is not terminated. It does not end with a double quote. Escape characters are internal to a string. Quotes delimit the start and end of a string.

Comment: Thats my bad then, however this doesnt affect anything. Since I scraped this data to a website using bs4 the escape characters aren't immediately converted to a readable form. And that's my question is

Comment: I can only deal with what you provide. Perhaps your problem is the escape characters that prevent the code working for you the same way it worked for me. Your code is correct, as I state in my answer. However, your data is suspect.

Comment: ... and parsing twice is definitely not something to consider.

Comment: I have edited my question to something more specific

Answer (score 0):

Read the following carefully --> [here](https://www.djangotemplatetagsandfilters.com/filters/json_script/) to understand the meaning of `JSON.parse` within `HTML` script tag.

Please consider the following points:

1. to get rid of Unicode within the HTML source, you've to use a real parser such as `lxml` which is the most speedy parser according to [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#installing-a-parser)
2. You can also use regex to parse it and pickup what between `{`...`}` where you can load it into `JSON` which will remove the Unicode.

```
import re
import json

html = """<script> 
var variable_json = JSON.parse("{\u0022id\u0022:1990,\u0022media_id\u0022:\u00225299\u0022}")
</script>"""


match = json.loads(re.search(r'({.*?})', html).group(1))
print(match)
```

Output:

```
{'id': 1990, 'media_id': '5299'}
```

Or

```
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<script> 
var variable_json = JSON.parse("{\u0022id\u0022:1990,\u0022media_id\u0022:\u00225299\u0022}")
</script>"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

print(json.loads(soup.select_one('script').string.split('"', 1)[-1][:-3]))
```

Output:

```
{'id': 1990, 'media_id': '5299'}
```

Comment: What does this mean? I need some sort of explanation

Comment: @Polaroid explanation submitted.